# Is it possible to set IIS Express service ID to an AD service Account

Tags: iis-express

I am attempting to debug an anomaly between IIS 7 and IIS Express.  My application runs fine in IIS 7 and when I debug it in Visual Studio/IIS Express.  However, I am required to change the service account the application runs under in IIS 7 (for password compliance reasons).  When I change the service account in the IIS 7 application pool to the new one I get an authentication error.  Both the old and new service accounts have exactly the same permissions.  There are 18 different authentications the app has to proceed through, and I'm having difficulty pinning down exactly where the issue is; I doubt the issue is any one of the 18 auths I see as those are user auths and do not appear to be related to the service account.

Regardless, I'd like to be able to debug this issue in Visual Studio.  Unfortunately, installing remote debugging or installing VS on the server is not an option.  I'm left with trying to debug the issue on my desktop (no installing IIS 7 on my desktop is also not an option).  Of course, IIS Express process executes under the logged in user's Windows account; is it possible to set the process to use an Active Directory Service Account instead?

Comment: You can run IIS Express as the service account since you have its credentials. Then run VS as administrator and attach to it. But again that's not exactly the same as full IIS.

Comment: Yeah...that's kinda what the question is...how do I run IIS Express as the service account.

Comment: So do you refer to "Group managed service accounts"?

Comment: @LexLi, to be honest I'm not sure if it's group managed or standalone managed; there's a whole IT team that manages the service accounts.  My guess is it's group managed as it's scope is across the entire domain.

Comment: If it is a group managed service account, then your hands are tied, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/getting-started-with-group-managed-service-accounts#BKMK_Intro You can only spin out IIS Express processes with that account if you use a Windows service stub or from Task Scheduler. Neither is simple, but technically doable.